# Cannot fix mismatch type : void to boolean

Tags: java, javafx

```
package application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;

public class AbsenceController {
    @FXML
    public DatePicker dateabs;

    @FXML
    public RadioButton justifier, nonjustifier;

    @FXML
    public Button ajouterabsence;

    @FXML
    void ajouterabsence(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            if (nonjustifier.setSelected(true)) {
                String query = "UPDATE bource SET bourcntage=bourcentage+5";
                Connection conn = (Connection) cnx.connectdb();
                PreparedStatement pr;
                pr = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                pr.executeQuery(query);
            }

            Connection pr;
            pr.close();
            Connection conn;
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a problem in line 27:

```
if (nonjustifier.setSelected(true))
```

with error:

> `mismatch type cannot convert from void to boolean`

Any solution?

Comment: It's telling you that your `if` clause is not operating on a boolean because you're calling a `void`, not `boolean` method

Comment: how can i solve it please ?

Comment: Please don't edit the original code like that yet, as now the question makes no sense at all. Plus it looks messed up in other ways too

Comment: if it looks messed up im so sorry , the problem is that my instructor gave me a source code of the app im working on and asked to firstly correct errors so i found this error in Eclipse IDE  and i couldn't find a way out to solve that's why i asked .

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I've used JavaFX, however what is happening here is you are checking a condition that is not a boolean.

The `setSelected(boolean)` method's return type is `void`, not `boolean`, meaning you are checking the conditions of something that has no `true` or `false`value. Essentially what you're doing is setting the value of `selected` to true, but there's nothing that comes as a result of doing that for you to check if the button has or has not been selected.

What I think you're looking for is

```
if(nonjustifier.isSelected())
```

The `isSelected()` method returns type `boolean`, which is what you need to evaluate an `if` condition.

[ToggleButton (Parent of RadioButton) official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html#isSelected--)

Comment: thanks a lot , it solved the issue but now in line 41 it says that pr cannot be resolved should i declare it as a local variable ?

Comment: @LoliPronoms Perhaps you should ask your teacher or a coach/tutor for help.